# Ruby: how to splice an array into a list Lisp-style?

Tags: ruby, lisp

This is something I find myself wanting to do occasionally. Say I have a list of arguments. In Lisp, I can go like

```
`(imaginary-function ,@args)
```

in order to call the function with the array turned from one element into the right number of arguments.

Is there similar functionality in Ruby? Or am I just using a completely wrong idiom here?

Comment: In Lisp that's neither a function call, nor an array. It's just a list with another list spliced in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes!  It's called the splat operator.

```
a = [1, 44]
p(*a)
```

Comment: `puts(a)` and `puts(*a)` have the same output

Comment: Yeah, not a great example.  I'll change it to "p(*a)".

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Seems a little weird syntactically that you use the same operator to collect (*args) in a function, but it makes sense mnemonically I guess.

Answer (score 3):

This is the splat operator: `function(*list)`